# Swiping through fragments then app crashed

Tags: java, android, androidx

Like a title , how can i fix it

Error

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.example.doanlttbdd.MainActivity@28acf243 must implement
>   OnFragmentInteractionListener

There is MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private TabsAccessorAdapter tabsAccessorAdapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar= findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("F9");

    viewPager= findViewById(R.id.main_tabs_paper);
    tabsAccessorAdapter= new TabsAccessorAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAccessorAdapter);

    tabLayout= findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}
```

Here is myAdapter

```
public TabsAccessorAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
    super(fm, behavior);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i){
        case 0:
            ChatsFragment chatsFragment=new ChatsFragment();
            return chatsFragment;
        case 1:
            GroupsFragment groupsFragment=new GroupsFragment();
            return groupsFragment;
        case 2:
            ContactsFragment contactsFragment=new ContactsFragment();
            return contactsFragment;
            default:
                return null;
    }
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return "Chats";

        case 1:
            return "Groups";

        case 2:
            return "Contacts";

        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

My chatsfragment

```
public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment {


public ChatsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);
}
```

the other fragment just like this 
i think it is bacause i'm using androidx so i cannot find any solution to fix it in the internet

RedLine in this `(getSupportFragmentManager())`

Comment: Isn't the error message clear `MainActivity@28acf243 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener`?

Comment: Please post your fragment classes

Comment: i have 3 fragment chats groups contacts and nothing in there

Answer (score 1):

The quick solution first then the explanation

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

It is gonna red lint the MainActivity, alt + enter and choose the solution it will add the missing methods.

The problem is one of your fragments need the parent activity implements that interface to be used as a callback. Probably the fragment is doing something like this

```
@Override
onAttach...
if context is casteable to the Interface then initialize a field, otherwise crash with the message
```

These are common patterns. The callback in the parent activity is used to coordinate with other fragments.It is a way to know when something happen on a fragment and then do something on other. The exception throwed is to make sure you implement the needed interface.

This also probably happen for using the fragment wizarf on Android Studio but not reading the checkbox `Include callback...`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new project.
2. create a pager adapter TabsPagerAdapter.java

   ```
   import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.GamesFragment;
   import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MoviesFragment;
   import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.TopRatedFragment;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

   public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
   public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
       super(fm);
   }

   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int index) {

       switch (index) {
       case 0:
           // Top Rated fragment activity
           return new TopRatedFragment();
       case 1:
           // Games fragment activity
           return new GamesFragment();
       case 2:
           // Movies fragment activity
           return new MoviesFragment();
       }

       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       // get item count - equal to number of tabs
       return 3;
   }
   }
   ```
3. Now create First Tab View fragment_top_rated.xml

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="#fa6a6a" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="Design Top Rated Screen"
      android:textSize="20dp"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


     </RelativeLayout>
   ```
4. now create TopRatedFragment.java

   ```
   import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.R;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;

   public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment {

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);
   return rootView;
     }

   }
   ```
5. similarly repeat step 3 and 4 to create GamesFragment and MoviesFragment and their XML
6. now create MainActivity.java

   ```
   import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
   import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.R;
   import android.app.ActionBar;
   import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
   import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
   import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
   import android.view.Menu;

   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
       ActionBar.TabListener {

   private ViewPager viewPager;
   private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
   private ActionBar actionBar;
   // Tab titles
   private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   // Initilization
   viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
   actionBar = getActionBar();
   mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

   viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
   actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

   // Adding Tabs
   for (String tab_name : tabs) {
       actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
               .setTabListener(this));
   }

   /**
    * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
    * */
   viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           // on changing the page
           // make respected tab selected
           actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
       }
     });
   }

   @Override
   public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
   // on tab selected
   // show respected fragment view
   viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
   }

   @Override
   public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

     }

   }
   ```

Comment: The 1st step of your solution is create a new project?

Comment: this is the step by step complete process that you can implement. according to the requirement, you can use this code in your project